# AngularTS: OAuth problems at first implementation - ERROR TypeError: this.logger.error is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth, openid, okta

It's my first time when i try to make OAuth in my app. I decided to make brand new angular app for this and at the beginning of my work i have big issue. I trying to figure out by google what is it (as i normally do), but can't find solution for this issue. I using this [guide](https://dev.to/ped4enko/how-to-build-an-angular-app-with-authentication-in-30-minutes-506k) and i get stuck in first step in OAuth:

> Import OAuthService into src/app/app.component.ts and make your app use the settings of your Okta app.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, JwksValidationHandler } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
    this.oauthService.redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    this.oauthService.clientId = '{client-id}';
    this.oauthService.scope = 'openid profile email';
    this.oauthService.issuer = 'https://dev-{dev-id}.oktapreview.com';
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();

    // Load Discovery Document and then try to login the user
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
      this.oauthService.tryLogin();
    });
  }

  title = 'Hotellove';

}
```

app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { OAuthService, UrlHelperService, OAuthLogger } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [OAuthService, UrlHelperService, OAuthLogger],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Error in visual code console after **ng serve**:

```
  ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(22,5): error TS2322: Type 'typeof OAuthLogger' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
      Type 'typeof OAuthLogger' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider'.
        Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

Error in browser console:

```
core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: this.logger.error is not a function
    at SafeSubscriber._error (angular-oauth2-oidc.js:1054)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:185)
    at SafeSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:137)
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at FilterSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:7)
```

Maybe somebody has solution for it or a better guide to make it?

Comment: Have you imported the `HttpClientModule` in your application module?

Comment: I figured out something but still have error, give me 5 min for updating my post. Edit: @R.Richards Updated!

Comment: At this moment when i try provide OAuthLogger app is starting with error posted above, when i delete it, i got not working app with error: No provider for OAuthLogger!

Comment: As explained in the tutorial, you need to import `OAuthModule` in your application module. BTW, that tutorial is referencing some deprecated libraries. You may continue to have issues if you keep following that. Good luck.

Comment: Use OAuthModule.forRoot() in the imports section. Thanks